# How do I transpose a range of data from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I believe I am correctly coping the range I need from my second worksheet but I do not understand where/how the paste works. I am trying to paste to a different worksheet.

```
Sub Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim dat As Variant

    With Worksheets(2) 
        Set rng = .[d31:o31] 
        dat = rng 
        rng.Clear 


        .Range(rng.Cells(1, 1), Cells(rng.Row, rng.Rows.Count)) = Application.Transpose(dat)
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Upper Boundaries of the array to determine the size of the destination.

Explicit parent worksheet references will help to determine proper range references.

```
Sub Click()

    Dim dat As Variant

    With Worksheets(2) 

        with .range(.cells(31, "D"), .cells(31, "O"))
            dat = .value
            .Clear
            .Cells(1, 1).resize(ubound(dat, 2), ubound(dat, 1)) = _
                Application.Transpose(dat)
        end with

    End With

End Sub
```

Within `.range(.cells(31, "D"), .cells(31, "O"))`, `.Cells(1, 1)` is `.cells(31, "D")` on the worksheet.